# Can Ghouls be damaged by fire?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

The Ghoul Resistant skin allows them to not get damaged by conventional weapons such as being pierced by knives and common low calibre firearms. (A shot from a tank would pierce them)

I was wondering if the ghoul resistant skin can be burned or damaged by fire/ice/acid/electricity?

We saw that they can have allergies to things, such as metal allergies. Since their skin can only be pierced by high impact force or other kagunes. I was thinking if a ghoul could be burned alive or the skin would resist that.

I know that regeneration would keep them alive if they are damaged, but I was wondering if you had a flamethrower or an acid bottle, would that go through their skin or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there never was that kind of interaction, beside

> when Tatara and Takizawa fought in Tokyo Ghoul:Re 2nd Season episode 3, but i dont know if that counted as fire. + Takizawa is kinda sadistic so im not really sure if his screams of pain weren't just sarcastic since he follows that with: "but that felt really good"

(I would love to provide more to that scene, but im not that familiar if it is possible to tag pictures as spoilers so i hope that the episode is enough as source)